# Difference of perfect power is prime infinitely often

Tags: number-theory

Famous Catalan conjecture implies that difference of power is 1 for only trivial solutions. One can generalize this and ask

> For given constant $c$, is a difference of two perfect power $c$ for only finitely often?

This is likely to be true and has a name followed by **Generalized Catalan conjecture**.

Difference of perfect power had several more interesting questions, such as **Fermat-Catalan conjecture** and many other Diophantine equations.

Given this point of view, one can ask more about the distribution of the difference of two perfect powers.

Now here is my question.

> Is difference of two perfect power a prime infinitely often?

Notice that difference of two perfect power can be $4k+1$ because $(2k+1)^2-2k^2=4k+1$. Since there are infinitely many primes in form of $4k+1$, It is trivial in this sense. So I would instead ask,

> Is difference of two perfect powers (that are not squares) a prime infinitely often?

I also notice that $k^3-1$ is squarefree infinitely often, so that will answer the case if one asks the easier variation of this question and replace prime with squarefree.

Are there any tries or results with this sortof topics? Thanks.

Comment: Are the exponents of the perfect powers arbitary ?

Comment: The Bunyakovsky-conjecture for example implies that there are infinite many positive integers $n$, such that $n^5-3^3=n^5-27$ is prime.

Comment: Yeah they are arbitrary. They just have to be a perfect power that is not square.

Comment: I also know that there are a lot of stronger version of this conjecture, such as the one you mentioned. But they are far more difficult to answer because I'm asking for all kinds of polynomials possible.

Comment: I do not know whether it can be proven, but I am pretty sure that the answer is yes.

Comment: I also heard that it is proven that $x^2+y^4$ is prime infinitely often, but It still doesn't quite answer...

Comment: You won't believe it, but I also thought of this :) But we do not even know whether $x^2+1$ produces infinite many primes. If you allow a cube and a square, the theory of elliptic curves might give a positive answer.

Comment: I would have no idea how to prove that $k^3-1$ is squarefree for infinite many positive integers $k$, although it seems obvious.